# For Loop Append to list from another

Tags: python, list

I'm working on a "pick up all" and "drop all" for a game I'm designing. The player has an inventory (inventory) and each room has it's own to keep track of what is in it. When it is a specific item, I can easily append or remove the item from the respective lists, but when it is for them all, I am not sure how to proceed. (NOTE: I won't know how many items are in the inventories as it will change as players take and drop items)

```
ROOMNAMEinventory = ['lamp', 'coin']
inventory = ['string']
do = raw_input("What would you like to do?").upper()
if(do == 'drop all'):
  for items in ROOMNAMEinventory:
    inventory.append(items)
    ROOMNAMEinventory.remove(items)
print inventory
print ROOMNAMEinventory
```

Currently, this prints out:

```
['string', 'lamp']
['coin']
None
```

Why does it print the None?

Comment: There must be a million duplicates for this : don't modify a list you iterate on.

Comment: Your code cannot generate the observed output. There is no third `print` statement to generate `None`, and `do` will never equal `'drop all'` because it will not contain any lowercase letters, being the return value of `str.upper()`.

Comment: for this particular example, you can use the `extend` and `clear` methods of list to do the same

Comment: Thanks for the .upper/.lower example. I've fixed it in the actual project.

Answer (score 1):

`List` in Python supports adding one to another:

```
roomname_inventory = ['lamp', 'coin']
inventory = ['string']
do = raw_input("What would you like to do?").upper()
if (do == 'DROP ALL'):
    inventory += roomname_inventory
    roomname_inventory = []
print inventory
print roomname_inventory
```

But if you just want to get rid of modifying the list while iterating over it, you could also do:

```
if (do == 'DROP ALL'):
    while roomname_inventory:
        inventory.append(roomname_inventory.pop(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

2 mistakes here

1. you convert to uppercase but test against lower!
2. you should iterate on a copy of `ROOMNAMEinventory`, modifying list while iterating on it is not recommended: it changes lists to that `['string', 'lamp']
   and ['coin']`: not that you want

Fixed code:

```
ROOMNAMEinventory = ['lamp', 'coin']
inventory = ['string']
do = raw_input("What would you like to do?").upper()
if(do == 'DROP ALL'):  # upper vs upper: could work :)
  for items in ROOMNAMEinventory[::]:  # iterate on a copy of the list
    inventory.append(items)
    ROOMNAMEinventory.remove(items)
print inventory
print ROOMNAMEinventory
```

result (when inputting `drop all`)

```
['string', 'lamp', 'coin']
[]
```

Comment: Thanks! That really does work. Could you also have it check something in the loop before adding/removing? Like if it had to be under a certain weight, could you make it check for each item?

Comment: define a dict: `wd = {'lamp' : 100, 'coin' : 1}` and check `if wd[items] < 10: do something`

Comment: I was thinking more of having a variable called AVALWEIGHT. Each time you picked up an item, it subtracted the item's weight from the AVALWEIGHT. For single picking up/dropping items, it is simple to either add or subtract the saved item weight (for drop all, it resets to original), but for the pick up all it doesn't work quite as well. For example: `AVALWEIGHT = 10` and `COINWEIGHT = 15` is there a way so that the coin won't change inventories but the other items (if they weigh less) will?

Comment: the dict I defined is a relation between name and weight. So you can do it this way.

Comment: Sorry, I am just new to Python. I'll go and work on that. Thanks!